# Mandelbrot set - Magnitude Decreasing Method (MDM/M)

Tags: complex-dynamics

Consider the following picture:

[image]

I made this this image the following way:

While computing $z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c$ with $z_0 = 0$ and $c$ being the point on the complex plane, check if $|z_{n+1}| < |z_n|$. If so, increase a counter $D$.
Repeat until $n > N_{max}$ or $|z_n| > 4$, where $N_{max}$ is the iteration limit.

If the iteration stops because $n > N_{max}$, then set $l = \frac{D}{N_{max}}$. If the iteration stops because $|z_n| > 4$, then set $l = D$

By plotting the value of $l$ for every point in the complex plane, one obtains the image above.

(Basically I am plotting how many times the absolute value of $z_{n+1}$ decreases compared to $z_n$)
(This works for julia-sets in a similar fashion.)

The interior of the main cardiod gets pretty messy, but everything else seems fine.

Now I have a question: Is this a known method?

I have got a second question regarding the image: At the value $-1.543689012692076361570855971801569$ the image shows a wierd cusp, and the corresponding Julia-set is a dendrite. Is this somehow related?

Comment: You have found the Misiurewicz point (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/479287)

Comment: Similar to : https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mandelbrot_Atom_Domains_Animation.gif    follow links to see more.

Comment: Thank you, Adam. This seems to be it. It is like the atom-domain method (described here: http://www.mrob.com/pub/muency/atomdomain.html ), but I increase a counter instead of taking the iteration where the magnitude is the smallest.

Comment: http://mathr.co.uk/blog/2015-02-01_misiurewicz_domains.html